# Cannot login to SQL Server using NHibernate, but with Management Studio or sqlcmd it works

Tags: c#, sql-server

Im getting login failed error when trying to connect to my database using NHibernate:

```
var config = Fluently.Configure()
              .Database(MsSqlConfiguration
              .MsSql2005
              .ConnectionString("Data Source=SERVER1\\SQLEXPRESS;Integrated Security=SSPI;Initial Catalog=xxx"))
              .Mappings(x => x.FluentMappings.AddFromAssembly(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly()));
```

With `Error 18456 State 5` in the log viewer in SQL Management Studio.

But using `sqlcmd` or Management Studio it works fine (using Windows Auth)!

What could be the problem?

**EDIT**
The NHibernate exception:

```
Test method ProjektLogg.Tests.NHibernateTests.ShouldBeAbleToGenerateFactory threw exception: 
FluentNHibernate.Cfg.FluentConfigurationException: An invalid or incomplete configuration was used while creating a SessionFactory. Check PotentialReasons collection, and InnerException for more detail.

 ---> NHibernate.HibernateException: Login failed for user XXX-INTRANET\username. ---> System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: Login failed for user XXX-INTRANET\username.
```

Comment: You're using your Windows network ID to log in via Management Studio?  Can you post the connection string you use for SQLCMD?

Comment: Figuring what the real error is, when connecting - http://sql-articles.com/articles/troubleshooting/troubleshooting-login-failed-error-18456/

Comment: Im using sqlcmd -E -S SERVER1\SQLEXPRESS

Comment: @shahkalpesh Yes i have read that, but it doesnt help me.

Comment: That syntax should work fine.  Can you post the exact exception message that NHibernate gives you?

Comment: @squillman Well, it is in swedish. But if i translate it i can post it. I will edit the question

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That error message means "Invalid UserID". If you're running IIS, make sure your application pool uses the same identity as the user who you are connecting to the database with in management studio.

If you're not running under IIS, make sure your current user account (Windows) can access the database, as you're using Integrated Security.

Link on the error: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/sql_protocols/archive/2006/02/21/536201.aspx

**EDIT: Hang on, you're missing Initial Catalog**. Try this:

```
"Data Source=SERVER1\\SQLEXPRESS;Integrated Security=SSPI;Initial Catalog=YourDatabase"
```

Comment: I assume my account can access the database since i can login through SQL Mgmnt Studio using Windows Auth, and also with sqlcmd -E

Comment: @ErikTJ Try `"Data Source=SERVER1\SQLEXPRESS;AttachDbFilename='YourDatabase.mdf';Integrated Security=True;User Instance=True"`

Comment: I dont want to attach a database, but i will try "User Instance=True"

Comment: No difference when using ";User Instance=True"

Comment: Using SSMS and sqlcmd you can connect, but can you also run your query successfully?  NHibernate will need to know what database you want to connect to and then you must have access to the database for it to do its mappings.  You can connect to the server with SSMS and sqlcmd without specifying a database to use.  If you don't tell NHibernate what db to use or don't have access to the db it won't be able to create the mappings. So, it's not necessarily safe to assume you have access to the db.

Comment: @ErikTJ curiously, specifying the user id and password in the connection string (purely just to test) and taking out the integrated security, does that work? As well as connecting, can you actually execute scripts against the database in management studio?

Comment: I tried to create a table using sqlcmd and it showed up in SSMS. Anyway, i cleaned the whole solution now it works. Sorry to waste your time, guys. Appreciate your answers.

Comment: @ErikTJ Ah that's good news, I'd hedge a bet on that you weren't actually specifying a database (Initial Catalog) was the actual fix, which took effect after the clean :)

Answer (score 1):

I faced a similar problem and I realized that unlike Entity Framework, (Fluent)NHibernate does not create a database for you. The solution was to create an empty database.

The following segment in your ConnectionString means that database xxx must already exist:

```
Initial Catalog=xxx
```

Answer (score 0):

I cleaned the whole solution now it works. Sorry to waste your time, guys. Appreciate your answers.

Answer (score 0):

I couldn't get it to work with Integrated Security, I had to supply a user and password in the connection string.